# Как настроить использование lz4 сжатия в модуле zswap?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Пытаюсь настроить модуль **zswap** таким образом, чтобы сжатие области подкачки
было бы включено с самого начала загрузки системы. Для этого в файле
`/etc/default/grub` задал параметры загрузки ядра:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="zswap.enabled=1 zswap.zpool=zsmalloc zswap.compressor=lz4"
```

И всё было бы хорошо, если б сжатие lz4 включалось бы само во время загрузки
(или сразу после, главное, чтобы не вручную). Однако используется значение по
умолчанию — lzo.

Содержимое файлов в каталоге `/sys/modules/zswap/parameters` таково:

```
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/compressor:lzo
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled:Y
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/max_pool_percent:20
/sys/module/zswap/parameters/zpool:zsmalloc
```

А вот вывод **dmesg**, относящийся к **zswap**:

```
[    1.140971] zswap: compressor lz4 not available, using default lzo
[    1.141064] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zsmalloc
```

Более того, если вручную после входа задать метод сжатия, он устанавливается без
проблем — содержимое файла меняется, **dmesg** рапортует об успехе, а такая
команда завершается без ошибок:

```
echo lz4 | sudo tee /sys/module/zswap/parameters/compressor
```

Но меня напрягает вводить такую команду каждый раз при включении компьютера. Как
заставить этот модуль ядра автоматически использовать сжатие lz4, без
дополнительных пинков вручную?

Система: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая ошибка в первые доли секунд работы системы вызвана отсутствием в этот
момент модуля, отвечающего за сжатие методом lz4. В Ubuntu по умолчанию
одноимённый модуль ядра не включен в состав начального загрузочного диска.
Поэтому придётся добавить его самостоятельно. Вот так:

```
echo lz4 | sudo tee -a /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

А после не забудьте перегенерировать этот диск:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```